Does the Wigner little group classification of particles have consequences for classical field theory?
Does the Wigner little group classification of particles have consequences for classical field theory? In particular, I'm curious whether it can be used to predict the two propagating modes for massless non-scalar particles in Poincare-invariant classical field theories.

I admittedly don't have an entirely solid understanding of the little group in quantum field theory, and I'm trying to see if maybe if I keep just to classical field theory, I might then feel a little more comfortable with the little group. However, it's not clear to me what the object I should be considering is; in the quantum case, I can consider breaking up the Hilbert space of states into irreps, but I'm not sure what the analogy is in the classical case (and whether there is indeed an analogy).

Depending on how you look at quantization, you could say there are consequences for classical field theory; whether there was first classical fields then they get quantized, or they were quantum all along but through quantum properties we learn of their classical structure. When I say classical structure, I am thinking of the field equations and the Lagrangian as a functional of classical fields.
A quantum field can be built from creation and annihilation operators
\begin{equation}
h^{r}(x) = \sum_{\sigma}\frac{d^3 \textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{2\omega_\textbf{p}}}\left(u^r(\textbf{p},\sigma)a(\textbf{p},\sigma)e^{-ipx} + v^r(\textbf{p},\sigma)a^\dagger(\textbf{p},\sigma)e^{ipx}\right)\,,
\end{equation}
where $r$ stands for any set of Lorentz indices and $\sigma$ stands for spin degrees of freedom.
From the transformation properties of single-particle states, you can learn about the transformation properties of the creation and annihilation operators under the Lorentz transformations. But since this field is also a function on spacetime, there should be a compatibility between the transformation of the creation and annihilation operators (LHS below) and the field as a function on spacetime (RHS below)
\begin{equation}
U(\Lambda)h^r(x)U^{-1}(\Lambda) = \sum_{s} L(\Lambda^{-1})^{rs} h^s(\Lambda x)
\end{equation}
where $L(\Lambda)$ is a representation of the Lorentz group on the space of fields (e.g. $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$ for vector fields).
You can now look at this compatibility equation more closely by focusing on the polarization functions $u^r(\textbf{k},\sigma)$ in the standard momentum $\textbf{k}$
$$\sum_{\sigma'}u^r(\mathbf{k},\sigma')\mathcal{D}_{\sigma'\sigma}(W^{-1}) =\sum_s L(W^{-1})^{rs}u^s(\mathbf{k},\sigma)$$
You learn about the matrices $\mathcal{D}_{\sigma'\sigma}(W^{-1})$ from Wigner's approach to classifying single particle states, and then you try to see what kind of objects $L(W^{-1})^{rs}$ you could choose on the RHS.
The polarization functions in the standard momentum thus carry the representation of the little group and contain also the information about the possible degrees of freedom described by that field.
For example, let's say you want to build a massless spin 1 field. A rotation around the standard momentum for an angle $\theta$ gives on the right hand side simply
\begin{equation}
u^{r} (k, 1) e^{ i\theta}\,.
\end{equation}
Then you choose what $r$ should be, i.e. what kind of an object $u^{r}$ should be, and try to make it work with the RHS. For instance, if we choose $u^r$ to be an antisymmetric Lorentz tensor of rank 2, then the compatibility equation should be
$$u^{\mu\nu}e^{i\theta} = R(\theta)^\mu{}_\alpha R(\theta)^\nu{}_\beta u^{\alpha\beta}$$
You find that this can work, and thus, that spin 1 massless particles can be described by rank two antisymmetric tensor fields. With this information you can continue on building your equations of motion and the Lagrangian and then work with them solely as classical objects.

This is hard to explain in a single post, so I can recommend some literature which explains this in detail. I especially like

S. Weinberg - Quantum theory of fields vol. 1
A. Duncan - Conceptual framework of quantum field theory
W. K. Tung - Group theory in physics


+1 Thank you for the answer. Just to confirm, should I view it that Wigner's classification constrains the quantum fields, which then constrains the classical fields?

Or maybe I can view $\sum_{\sigma'}u^r(\mathbf{k},\sigma')\mathcal{D}_{\sigma'\sigma}(W^{-1}) =\sum_s L(W^{-1})^{rs}u^s(\mathbf{k},\sigma)$ already as a classical equation, without any reference to the unitary $U$ that induced it?

Practically, yes. Even though the equation form your last comment stemmed from Wigner's classification of single particle states, it can now be viewed classically to see what types of fields one could use for which types of particles.
